# Biggest Rectangle within one color

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing, computational-geometry

I struggle to find a solution to the following problem :

I used opencv to mark all connected white pixels with a unique label.

Now i got a group of those elements. 
Those objects often are 90% rectangular but most of the time contain some extra lines and stuff.

Im searching for a algorithm which does thr following :

-get biggest Rectangle out of image(within the same label) 
- fast performance 
-maybe even filter,  larget rectangle which contains at least xx% Pixels with the same label

Maybe someone can help me
Thanks a lot
Edit: Example Pictures(in this case fo licence plate location):
my desired output of the algorithm would be the rectangle of the plate(and of curse all other rectangles in the image, im gonna filter them later)

Important the rectangles may be rotated !

[image: Marked some example rectangles red]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could show an image to explain the problem...

Comment: good idea thanks, did

Comment: Have you tried using cv::findContours (maybe after a canny edge detector) and then cv::minAreaRect for each contour.

Comment: I don't like that approach. With most of the worlds license plates you can't just look for a blob in a gradient image with bloated edges.
You won't find rectangles without a lot of effort among your connected components as they are part of bigger components.
Please provide your input image.

Comment: @user4834736 : In number plate detection ,finally you need number of car.So i suggest you to use OCR module from opencv to extract text from image.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion

- make sure to fill small holes either by blob analysis or mathematical morphology;
- compute the distance map in the white areas;
- binarize the distance map with a threshold equal to the half plate height.

The rectangles will appear as line segments long as the plate width minus the plate height. You may locate them by fitting rotated rectangular bounding boxes; they must have a large aspect ratio.

Comment: @user4834736: unfortunately, this is not bulletproof. You will get both false negatives and false positives.

Comment: I suggest you improve your preprocessing first. You merge too man things by having such fat gradient lines.
Also limit your search area. license plates will only travel through narrow paths in your image. you know where the road is and where to expect plates to move along. By that you can get rid of at least 80% of disturbing information.

Comment: @Piglet: 80% is excessive. Cars can change lanes, trucks have higher guard clearance. 20% is more realistic. Fat lines a required to ensure that the plate is seen as a solid area with characters erased.

Comment: how many cars will change lane in your field of view? 1/10000? you'll have significantly more license plates that are covered by cars on the other lane at the camera angles he chose. So it does not really matter to lose a few more.

Comment: @Piglet: hem, let us admit that 1/10000 is not another exaggeration.